# How to set ID/class to background image of a class

Tags: jquery, css

How do I set an ID to the background image of a container so that I can adjust its properties? Unfortunately, I can't just call the image from the html file because the image changes dynamically (track.artwork_url)

```
$('.musiccontroller').css('background-image', 'url(' + track.artwork_url + ')');

    $('.musiccontroller').css({ 

     "background-size": "100%",
      "-webkit-filter": "blur(10px)",
      "opacity": ".5"
});
```

(Right now, this makes the entire container blurry and opaque)

Comment: Only HTML Element can have an ID.  Background-Image is a css style, not an HTML Element.  So it would appear that it's literally impossible to do exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A background image is attached to an element which can have an ID. You can't have an ID on the background image itself. All of the properties to modify the background image can be applied to the element that has the background image. If you need more control, you can absolute position a before/after pseudo element or create another DOM element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been said, you can't add an ID to the background image, but you should be able to achieve the affect you want with this. Optimizing this to use CSS where possible would be a good idea.

```
$('.musiccontroller').css('position', 'relative');
$('<div class="musiccontroller-bg"></div>')
    .css({
        'background-image', 'url(' + track.artwork_url + ')'
        "background-size": "100%",
        "-webkit-filter": "blur(10px)",
        "opacity": 0.5,
        "position": "absolute",
        "left": 0,
        "right": 0,
        "top": 0,
        "bottom": 0
    })
    .appendTo($('.musiccontroller'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and in this particular case that means the only control you can exert on the background is by setting the [background-related CSS properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/) accordingly.

If you wanted full CSS control you 'd have to put the background inside an element that exists specifically for that purpose and then compose that element into the layout in a way that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, if you're using an div ID it should be #musiccontroller.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#musiccontroller').css({"background-size": "100%","-webkit-filter": "blur(10px)","opacity": ".5"});
});
```

Now the background image of #musiccontroller will have be changed according to your CSS adjustments once page loads. So just set your background image as the background of #musiccontroller, or make another divider to use as a background container if you don't want to manipulate #musiccontroller.